# Help! How to get the PDF-File? Error & Warnings lead to no pdf-file

Tags: errors, key-value

I have a big problem. I am writing my phd thesis and started to use latex recently. I developed some basic skills that helped out me most time. But at the moment I dont know how to solve the problem. Every time I try to typeset the tex-file, the console says this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Promotion4.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian
, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, u
kenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, 
german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, assamese,
 bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, 
telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji, lao, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, roma
nian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish,
 turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/ngermanb.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/applemac.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle-icomp.bb
x (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle-icomp.cb
x) (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg)

Package csquotes Warning: Option 'babel' depreciated.
(csquotes)                Using 'autostyle' on input line 2327.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfescape.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hycolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/xcolor-patch.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)

/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:3577: Packag
e keyval Error: cross-reference undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3577 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

I tried all the shortcuts to ignore the warnings and errors, but nothing helps. In the end I dont get the pdf-file and I it feels like destroying all the work  I have done so far.

So if anyone knows how to fix the problem, that would be great.

Comment: Without a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), we are not going to be able to say what is wrong.

Comment: Don't panic. It is an hyperref error and these are always solved fast. Check at first your hyperref version. E.g. in the log. If it is older than mine
(`2011/04/17 v6.82g`) update and then try again.

Comment: @ Joseph: Thanks for the commend. What you touched upon is the next part of the problem. I dont know what minimal example in this case would look like. Shall I provide an example of the preamble? Or a piece of text including some commands?

Comment: @Philip: Have a look at the link Joseph provided. Basically, a MWE is a tex-sample that _only_ contains what's necessary to reproduce the problem. You can get there by stripping your document of elements/parts/things one by one (e.g. starting with big text passages, other packages ...), compiling in between to make sure the problem's still there. This way, you can narrow down the source of the problem. For more details, follow the link.

Comment: Now that I see the output in a code environment: The problem is probably a wrong option. E.g.`\usepackage[cross-reference]{hyperref}` would give this error.

Comment: @doncherry. Thank you for the advise. When I read it I got aware that I dont know exactly what part of this huge console output indicate the problem. Is it just this part?:

 /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:3577: Packag
e keyval Error: cross-reference undefined.

Comment: @ulrike: Thank you for your help. I crossed out the cross-reference-option. Now the console is working better and stops at a later stage. So, I have the feeling that a part of the problem is solved. I still learn and try how to install an up to date version of the hyperref-package.

Comment: @ulrike: As I said in my comment before, I deleted the cross-reference-option and it seemed to work. But now I saw, that another two problems occured that - i guess - are related to the deleting. Now the console does NOT generate 

a) all those commands which belong to two the \label, \nameref etc. group. 
b) my bibliography built by biblatex.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Look at the first comment from Joseph: Don't let us guess what you are doing but show it.

Comment: @ulrike: Here my minimal example, that creates the consoles statement "l. 3577 \ProcessKeyvalueOptions{Hyp}?"
Minimal example \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cross-reference]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Comment: @Philip: that isn't a very useful minimal example. As Ulrike said (May 23), passing `cross-reference` as an option to `hyperref` will always give an error, because `cross-reference` is not a valid option (see the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) ). You need to edit your question to show something that you expect to work (so don't add '`cross-reference`') but doesn't. Then others might be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, the MWE is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cross-reference]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

As observed by others, `cross-reference` is not a valid option for `hyperref`, so the error message is entirely correct.